# What is the oldest version of Ubuntu snapcraft can run on?

Tags: snap

One of the andvantages of Snap packages over DEB ones is that the dependencies are contained in the package, hence a Snap should not break even if the system is updated.

Some old programs were meant to run on top of Qt3 and they have been removed from the repositories, because Ubuntu dropped support for it. I was thinking it might be possible to build a snap for such programs, but the easier way would be to install `snapcraft` on an old Ubuntu virtual machine and build the snap there.

So, what is the oldest Ubuntu that can run it? I'm not looking for a *supported* installation path or pre-built binaries. Just the practical limit, even if I were to build `snapcraft` from source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you'll quickly run into issues trying to run snapcraft 2.x on anything older than xenial, as it has dependencies that are only available in xenial.

I suggest trying to build Qt3 from source as a snapcraft part.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does that also apply for `snapcraft` 1.x?

Comment: No actually. I've used Snapcraft 1.x successfully all the way back to trusty. However, keep in mind that snapcraft 1.x can only create snaps for snappy Ubuntu Core 15.04, not 16.

Comment: Ah! Does that mean that snaps running on 15.04 are not compatible with later Ubuntu versions?

Comment: Indeed it does. Snaps in 15.04 were based on the older Click technology (what is currently used in the phones). Snaps in 16.04 aren't, and utilize squashfs. That said, the changes necessary for an application that is packaged as a snap in 15.04 to make it work in 16.04 are very minimal, it's just the packaging format that has changed.